# PhoneGap + jQuery Mobile + cakePHP

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have made a full application in JQM using cakePHP as the server side language. Application at this stage is only available via the browser.

I have used standard SQL in PHP to pull all data and I am not using JSON at all. My question is do I have to pretty much ditch cakePHP to get my application working on iPHONE and adopt a more JSON approach?

I am quite new to JSON and have issues in regards to how i'll handle access control and controlling what data is visible to certain users.

My thoughts so far would be to build a template for Phonegap so the app works offline and offers relevent error messages and my other app could be loaded into it once the user choose to login?

Any ideas or nudge in the right direction would be tops.

Comment: I answered below about using JSON and PHP.  For the part about "build a template for Phonegap so the app works offline", you could look at frameworks that have some functionality provided for doing MVC (like Backbone.js or a million others). This would work as long as the page was not reloaded. The data is stored in memory, synced via Ajax with the server when it can, and if it can't then you can register an error callback to handle that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP can use json via the built-in functions json_encode and json_decode.  So you can continue using CakePHP as the backend if you want, the client should neither know nor care.

For PHP JSON documentation, see: http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

The use of JSON is a choice of what format you send data in between the client and server.  JSON happens to be convenient on the client side which is written in Javascript.  You don't need to use JSON to make an iPhone-friendly web site / web app.

My general approach is to have a `toJSON` function on my PHP data objects.  I have a function that I use to send JSON to the client, and it first looks for the `toJSON` method before sending the object.  If it finds that, it calls it and sends the result of that.  This gives the object a chance to present a minimal set of data members as opposed to sending everything.  This is the same basic approach used in Ruby on Rails too.

Here's an example.  Perhaps CakePHP has their own equivalent of this:

```
function sendJSON($data) {
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
    header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');

    echo json_encode_custom($data);
    //echo '(' . json_encode($data) . ')';
}

function json_encode_custom($data) {
    if( is_object($data) && method_exists($data, 'toJSON') )
            $data = $data->toJSON();
    return json_encode($data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always keep you cakePHP site.

Since phonegap can only have html, css and javascript, you need a remote server to provide an API service so that the app can request data from the remote server via javascript. Then the remote server can answer the request by encoding the data in json format.